# (Java - LibGDX) How to rotate a vector to a certain rotation around another vector

Tags: java, math, vector, rotation

I have a vector called, say, `ship` which every frame I need to set to a certain rotation around another vector called `center`. Here's a picture to show what I mean.
[image]

As you can see, I'd like to be able to rotate `ship` to any rotation around `center`, preferably in a function with 2 `Vector2` parameters for the positions and then a `float` for the rotation (in degrees).

Comment: Two things: 1. Are you using the Vectors from com.badlogic.gdx.math package?  2.  How familiar are you with linear algebra?  Because it looks like you might be implementing some matrix multiplication here, or adding in org.apache.commons.math3.linear

Comment: Yes, I'm using the vectors from com.badlogic.gdx.math.package; and I'm not very familiar at all with linear algebra (I think, unless it's just a fancy name for something)

Comment: In mathematical terms, vector manipulations are often modeled as multiplying the vector in the form of a column matrix (n by 1) by a square matrix (n by n.  The result of that multiplication is another column matrix (n by 1) representing the transformed vector.  Here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) to how it is done in SVG.  They explain it much better than I could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mathematical functions to rotate a point around another point are:

```
double new_x = current_x * Math.cos(angle) - current_y * Math.sin(angle);
double new_y = current_x * Math.sin(angle) + current_y * Math.cos(angle);
```

if your center isn't at (0,0), you should first substract it at the current values, then add them again at the end like so:

```
double new_x = (current_x-center_x) * Math.cos(angle) - (current_y-center_y) * Math.sin(angle) + center_x;
double new_y = (current_x-center_x) * Math.sin(angle) + (current_y-center_y) * Math.cos(angle) + center_y;
```

Beware, your angle should be in radians and not in degrees, a easy conversion happens like so:

```
double angle = Math.toRadians(degrees);
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks - but just to confirm: is current_x the ship's position and is center_x the position to rotate round?

Comment: It doesn't really work... unless I'm just doing something else wrong - does it work for you?

Comment: Yep, I messed up the new y value, I'll correct that for you.